# How to sum values from array of objects

Tags: arrays

I gave array of objects

```
array = [rep_type: "working", time_spend: "325", ....;rep_type: "extra", time_spend: "100", ..... ;...]
```

I need to calculate sums for particular "rep_typ"s how can I do that?
Ex:
"working" - 500
"extra" - 200

Comment: seems to be ruby. but it's not valid notation...

Comment: Yes it ruby, its schematic notation

Comment: doubt it. and "schematic notation" is not a valid term (no google hits for ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = Hash.new(0)
a.each { |o|
  result[o.rep_type] += o.time_spend
}
```